# lvalue required as left operand of assignment C++

Tags: c++, eclipse

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int printR(int,int);
void foo(int);
int y=3;

int main()
{
    foo(6);
int x=3;

    printR(x,y);

}

void foo (int x)
{

    cout << x+5 << endl;
    cout << y;
}
int printR(int g, int t)
{
int z;
    g+t = z;

    cout << z;
}
```

Pretty simple code, but eclipse gives me an error saying that the statement "g+t=z"; gives an error, shouldn't it just add the values 3 and 3 together?  I already declared z as an int so not sure.

Comment: Assignment goes from right to left (the value on the right is assigned to the variable on the left) so if you want to assign the sum of `g` and `t` to `z`, that would be `z = g + t;`

Answer (score 0):

An assignment expression copies the value of the right operand into the left operand. You cannot assign a value to `g+t`; it doesn't make any sense! You can only change `g` and `t` individually. If you want to set the value of `z`, you have to put `z` on the left hand side.

```
z = g+t;
```

Better yet, set the value of `z` on initialization:

```
int z = g+t;
```